# Disable AirPort Extreme firewall

Tags: network, airport, time-capsule, router

Currently, I have a AirPort Extreme as WiFi router to which all my devices connect. It is configured in bridge mode and is connected to my ISPs router via WAN port which works just fine.

My goal is to use the ISP router as the primary router to which all devices connect and to use the AirPort just for its Time Capsule capability. The problem is that if I'm connected to my ISPs router, I don't have access to my AirPort Extreme which is in Bridge Mode. There is a ping timeout and I also cannot connect to its network share.

How can I configure the AirPort to allow access from outside?

Comment: There is a separate application to configure the APE. Not sure it‘s still part of macOS but if it is it should be in /Applications/Utilities. Having said that: hope you are aware that the HD in the APE is already rather old and may not be the best TM backup target.

Comment: Also, not sure what your question is about here: which firewall do you want to disable (there is none in bridge mode), and what do you mean with access from outside‘